# Service account expiration date

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I would to used "settings/iam-serviceAccountKeyExpiry" to set expiration date on service accounts on folders or projects.

https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/resource-settings/resource-settings#iam-serviceAccountKeyExpiry

But I don't understand how to set up this parameter in resource manager

https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/resource-settings/manage-resource-settings#change_a_local_setting_value

thanks for your help

Comment: At this time you must request access. https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScDvl-CPHC5xs2oK-eTqQ1ydF5vxcMXIKx7lrjOyK0V_spWnw/viewform In case that link is broken, search on this page: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating